# EasyMock expect to call method with Collection type of parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, collections, easymock

I ran into problem:

```
expect(dao.save(collectionOfElements)).andReturn(otherCollection);
```

And when I replay then I call this DAO method with then I get

```
Unexpected method call save(someObj1, someObj2) 
save(someObj1, someObj2): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

someObj1 from unexpected call equals to someObj1 from expected call and elements are even in same order.

At first I solved this that way:

```
expect(dao.save(isA(Collecion.class))).andReturn(otherCollection);
```

but now I have to test that does my service class calls dao.save with collection containing exactly 2 elements, so the `isA(Collecion.class)` doesn't work anymore.

How to solve this problem? Than You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that the first someObj1 and second someObj1 have the same toString (so appear the same) but they are not equals() == true.

I would check that the elements of the collections will be equal for your content.

Comment: Yes, someObj contains org.joda.DateTime type variable and that causes problems because it doesn't have hasCode and equals methods..